# Using completable to chain observable creation

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Can we create observable based on `completable.onComplete()` to replace if/else inside observable.onCreate() ?

```
completable
.(if onComplete() called, then continue to create observable)
```

Comment: That's what `andThen()` operator used for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42684401/7045114

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. Here is what I came up with:

```
myCompletable.andThen(
    Observable.just(true)
      .flatMap(
        ignoreIt -> createAnObservable(...)
      )
);
```