# How to perform sequential operation with too much Completable methods

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

I am trying to save the data on the server to the local database with Room. Since these tables are related to each other, I want the insertion to be done in order.I listen to these operations with RxJava. For example i have school's and season's tables and  and that's how I add the data:

```
fun insertAllSchools(vararg schools: School):Completable=dao.insertAll(*schools)

fun insertAllSeasons(vararg seasons: Season):Completable=dao.insertAll(*seasons)
```

When I create a separate method for each table, the insertion process is done, but I have to write a disposable method for each of them. Like this:

```
fun insertAllSchools(allData:ResponseAll){
        if(allData.schoolList!=null){
            disposable.add(
                    repositorySchool.insertAll(*allData.schoolList.toTypedArray())
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableCompletableObserver(){
                                override fun onComplete() {
                                    Log.d(TAG,"OnComplete")
                                }
                                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                                    Log.e(TAG,"Error"+e.localizedMessage)
                                }

                            })
            )
        }
    }
```

When one is complete, I call the other method, but this time there is a lot of unnecessary code.

I have tried different methods to combine these completable methods and work sequentially, but it does not add to the database even though it appears in the logs.

For example, I tried to combine it this way:

```
if(allData.schoolList!=null){
            mObservable = Observable.fromArray(
                    repositorySchool.clearAllData(),
                    repositorySchool.insertAll(*allData.schoolList.toTypedArray())
            )

            disposable.add(
                    mObservable
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<Completable>() {
                                override fun onComplete() {
                                    Log.d(TAG,"onComplete")
                                    isDataLoad.value = true
                                }
                                override fun onNext(t: Completable) {
                                    Log.d(TAG,"onNext"+t)
                                }
                                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                                    Log.e(TAG,"onError")
                                }
                            })
            )
        }
```

I do not receive any errors. How can I combine these completable methods and make them work sequentially. Thanks!

Edit(Solution): It works like this:------------>

```
if(allData.schoolList!=null) {
            disposable.add(
                    repositorySchool.clearAllData()
                            .andThen(Completable.defer { repositorySchool.insertAll(*allData.schoolList.toTypedArray()) })
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                                override fun onComplete() {
                                    isDataLoad.value = true
                                }

                                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                                    Log.e(TAG,""+e.localizedMessage)
                                }

                            })
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with using `doOnComplete()`. In that case your not combining the Completables into a single Completable event that you can observe. What you probably want is something like `doThingA().andThen(Completable.defer(() -> doThingB())` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51866155/11504837) answer on a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called `doOnComplete()` which you can use to make your second call through a lambda or jack.