# Improve chaining multiple (three) Completables by using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-kotlin

I want to invoke one Completable after another. That is when first is finished, invoke second and when the second is finished, invoke the third one. I already tried some different stuff like andThen(), but found out it does not "wait" for previous Completable to finish as it runs parallel. So far, this is what I have found and it works as I wanna, but is there any better way to improve this. Is there any operation function or something to get rid of Completable.defer at every stage?

Here is so far working example:

```
   private fun invokeAllThreeDoSomeLogic() {
        
        disposable.add(Completable.concatArray(
                Completable.defer {
                    firstApi.getData().doOnError { t: Throwable? ->
                        Timber.w(
                            t,
                            "first error"
                        )
                    }
                },
                Completable.defer {
                    Completable.fromObservable(secondApi.getData()
                        .doOnError { t: Throwable? ->
                            Timber.i(
                                t,
                                "Second error"
                            )
                        }
                },
                Completable.defer {
                    thirdApi.refresh().doOnError { t: Throwable? ->
                        Timber.i(
                            t,
                            "Third error"
                        )
                    }
                }
            ).subscribe(
                { },
                { t: Throwable? ->
                    Timber.w(t, "something went wrong")
                })
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FlatMap](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) for chained api call. It will be like

```
firstApi.getData()
   .flatmap(dataFromApi1 -> return secondApi.getData())
   ......
   ......
```

Check [this](https://medium.com/@amitadvaita/chaining-api-calls-using-rx-java-ad8761f3c9ef) medium blog for better understanding.

Edit:

For Completable you can use `andThen` operator .

```
firstCompletable
    .andThen(secondCompletable)
```

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42684401/1292557).

From that answer:

> In general, this operator is a "replacement" for a flatMap on
> Completable:

Comment: Good idea but I tried it.  The problem is I can not invoke flatMap on completable as firstApi.getData returns Completable(). Or am I wrong?

Comment: You don't need `Completable` , you can use `Single` as its an api. Check the blog link

Comment: You are correct, but it is not my decision what type should be returned.

Comment: Updated my answer for `Completable` , please check

Comment: Yea, as I said in question text, did try andThen(sec).andThen(third) but it does not go from first-> sec -> third...It runs parallel. It is important to run one after another when finished.

Comment: I tried your solution andThen(Completable.defer {sec}) and it works!